# .apk signing fails even with Sun JDK (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.jarutils.DebugKeyProvider)

Tags: android, fedora

I'm having an interesting problem signing my Android application, whether or not I'm using a debug key. Regardless of the JDK I have installed to `/usr/bin/{java,keytool,jarsigner}` (OpenJDK or Sun's JDK) it will always give the following output after compiling successfully:

```
-package-debug-sign:
[apkbuilder] Creating RemoteNotify-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

BUILD FAILED
/home/ianweller/AndroidSDK/platforms/android-7/templates/android_rules.xml:281: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ianweller/AndroidSDK/platforms/android-7/templates/android_rules.xml:152: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.jarutils.DebugKeyProvider
```

The application was built and signed just fine by Eclipse with the ADT plugin (even without Sun's JDK installed). I'm on Fedora 12.

I'm wanting to get my code out of Eclipse and move it into a git repository, but being unable to build it from ant will not allow this to happen.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, i'm getting the same error on Fedora 13?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the same error, same problem. I'm currently investigating the possibility of a classpath problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but watch out for odd characters, some fields cannot have spaces, commas, periods etc...